# Questions about continuity in the function $f(x+y)= f(x)+f(y)$ for each $x,y \in \Bbb{R}$.

Tags: calculus, functions

$f: \Bbb{R}\rightarrow\Bbb{R}$ is continuous in zero, s.t $f(x+y)= f(x)+f(y)$ for each $x,y \in \Bbb{R}$.

A. calculate $f(0)$ and prove that $f(-x)=-f(x)$

B. prove that $f$ is continuous in $\Bbb{R}$

for A, I reached that the limit when $x$ goes to zero must be equal to the value $f(0)$, by the definition of continuity, which means that $x+y$ must go to zero, and that way x can go to $-y$ which is the same thing, then I put $-y$ in the function and see what value I get, at the end i got:

$\lim \limits_{x \to -y}$$f(x+y) = f(-y)+f(y)$.

and I know from the information I have about the function $f(x+y)= f(x)+f(y)$ that $f(y)+f(-y) = f(0)$, but didn't know how to continue from here. and I don't have any direction for B. any kind of help would be appreciated.

Comment: For A, put in $x=y=0$ to get $f(0)=0$.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation

Comment: [This is a related question I asked some time back](/questions/1032565/functions-that-satisfy-fxy-fxfy-and-f1-e). You can derive the values of $f(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{Q}$ if you know the value for one nonzero point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$f(0)=0$ is shown as indicated by @user109899.

For B):
$$\lim_{y\to 0}f(x+y)=\lim_{y\to 0}f(x)+\lim_{y\to 0}f(y)=f(x)+f(0)=f(x) $$
by the hypothesis of continuity at $0$ and point A.

Comment: ok, but I must conclude here that $f(0)=0$ ? if yes then why is that?

Comment: He's showing (b), not (a). You prove (a) by noting that $f(0)+f(0)=f(0+0)=f(0)$.

Answer (score 3):

If $y=0$ we get
$$f(x)=f(x)+f(0)\quad\Longrightarrow\quad f(0)=0$$
If $y=-x$ we get
$$0=f(0)=f(x)+f(-x)\quad\Longrightarrow\quad -f(x)=f(-x)$$

Now, since $f$ is continuous at $x=0$, we know that
$$\forall \epsilon>0\quad\exists\delta>0\quad \text{such that}\quad |x|<\delta \quad\Longrightarrow\quad|f(x)|<\epsilon$$
In particular, fix any $x\in\mathbb{R}$, now for all $y\in \mathbb R$ we have
$$|y-x|<\delta \quad\Longrightarrow\quad|f(y)-f(x)|=|f(y-x)|<\epsilon$$
Thus, $f$ is continuous at $x$.

Comment: can you explain the last line? and where did u get  $|y-x|<\delta $ from ?

Comment: It is not just $|y-x|<\delta$. You should read **If** $|y-x|<\delta$, **then** $|f(y)-f(x)|<\epsilon$.

Comment: I knew how to read it, but I didn't get the logic behind it!

Comment: That implication turns out to be the definition of continuity of $f$ at a point $x$.

Comment: It is the continuity of $f$ in zero, using $y-x$ instead of $x$ in the original sentence. The fact that $f(y-x) = f(y) - f(x)$ is very important here.

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ is locally bounded and $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$, then $f(n x)=n\,f(x)$ for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$, so
$$|f(x/n)|=\frac{1}{n}|f(x)|$$
gives that $f(0)=0$ and $f$ is continuous in zero. From $0=f(0)=f(x)+f(-x)$ we get that $f$ is an odd function, and from $|f(x+y)-f(x)|=|f(y)|$ we get that $f$ is everywhere continuous, by considering $y\to 0$. Along the same lines, we can prove that if $f$ is locally bounded and $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$, then $f(x)=\alpha x$ for some $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: can you explain why is $"f(n x)=n\,f(x)"$ true?

Comment: $f(x)+f(x)=f(2x), f(x)+f(x)+f(x)=f(x)+f(2x)=f(3x)$ and so on.